# Magento: How do i still display products in category anchor is set to NO?

Tags: magento, anchor, product

The website is for samsung accesories.

So, menu item is Accesories > Samsung > Mobile Phones > other 8 subcategories. When i click on Samsung i do not want the attributes to be displayed on layered navigation. So i tried with anchor >NO, but i need the products. I need this because under Samsung i will have Mobile phones, Vacuum, fridge, air conditioner, etc.., with their on custom attributes sets.

I can transform subcategories for Mobile Phones into attributes, but the products will be all over. Can anybody help?

Comment: The `anchor` option only disables the layered navigation, it should still be displaying the products without the navigation sidebar.

Comment: No, when the anchor is set to no the products are not displayed "There are no products matching the selection." the products are in childs. I have main Cat. Samsung, with n subcats, and the "n" has subcategories too.

Comment: What I am telling you is how Magento is supposed to work not how it works on your install because I don't know nearly anything about your install.

Comment: The fact that your products are not visible on the parent category only means that they are not (directly) associated with that category. In the product editing menu on the category tab you can set a product to be associated with multiple categories (checkboxes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mihai. I understood. I tried to find an option wich disables attributes on layered nav with products displayed. Mihai, you're right on the spot. I'll try to do that. I forgot than has multiselect categories. Thank you.

Comment: Nota bene: you can also edit products from the Category editing page (from the products tab) which allows you to do some mass-associations instead of taking each product individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Layerd vs. normal navigation

The anchor option only disables the layered navigation, it should still be displaying the products (without the layered navigation sidebar) if they are associated directly to the category.

### Product visibility

The fact that your products are not visible on the parent category only means that they are not (directly) associated with that category. In the product editing menu on the category tab you can set a product to be associated with multiple categories.

### Product/category associations

You can also edit products from the Category editing page (from the products tab) which allows you to do some mass-associations instead of taking each product individually.

Answer (score 0):

Open the product you want to show in the samsung category then on the categories tab check the "samsung" category also.This will show the products in samsung category.